# Matching a single word inside optional parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I am using java regex to match a specific platform.
For example, my list of strings are:

```
Ruby 2.1 (Puma)
Ruby 2.3 (Passenger Standalone)
Ruby 2.2 (Puma)
Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)
Ruby 1.9.6
```

From these I want to only pick the ones which are not Passenger standlone. ie. Ruby 2.1 (Puma) and Ruby 2.2 (Puma) and Ruby 1.9.6. The only restriction/condition is that the version name i.e Puma or Passenger Standalone is optional. And therefore the parenthesis and the string inside the parenthesis are optional

I am trying to use the following regex:

```
"Ruby (.*)\s+\(?\w{0,1}\)?$"
```

I have the options as an ArrayList of Strings. My method code looks like:

```
public void displayVersions(String platform) {
    String regex = "Ruby (.*)\s+\(?\w{0,1}\)?$";
    List<String> availableVersions = getAvailableVersions();
    List<String> filtered = availableVersions.stream()
        .filter(version -> version.matches(regex))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(filtered);
```

}

The regex is incorrect and I am not getting the correct results. I get the Passenger Standalone versions only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just `.filter(version -> version.indexOf("Passenger Standalone") < 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed regex: `Ruby ([0-9.]+)\s?\(?[^\s]*\)?$`

You may also need to add `/m` option if the string to match is multiline

I personally suggest you https://regex101.com to check and debug regexes. For example https://regex101.com/r/c148v8/2

Comment: I was using regexr. Maybe that was doing something finicky. But also wouldn't this match the passenger Standalone versions as well? There's no restriction on that I guess?

Answer (score 0):

`Ruby [0-9.]+ \((\S)\)`

This will do the trick.

`Ruby [0-9.]+` matches the ruby version

`\((\S)\)` matches any non-whitespace char within parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested optionals:

```
^Ruby \d+(\.\d+)*( \(?\w+\)?)?$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/7nRJzJPdpe).